# Laravel al pasar coleccion de una vista a un controlador solo muestra el ultimo registro

Tags: laravel, livewire

tengo el siguiente escenario
en la vista tengo esto en un modal

```xml
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="order-listing" class="table table-striped mt-0.5 table-bordered table-sm red shadow-lg mt-4">
      <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:200px;" scope="col">Materias</th>
          <th style="width:40px;" scope="col">Not 1</th>
          <th style="width:40px;" scope="col">Not 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @if (isset($detalles))
          @foreach ($detalles as $key => $detalle)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $detalle->nombremat }}</td>
              @if ( $detalle->estado == '')
                <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width: 40px" value="{{ $detalle->nota1 }}" id="cobertura_1" data-id-validador="cobertura_1_validar"
                onkeyup="veinte(this)" onkeydown="num(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width: 40px" value="{{ $detalle->nota2 }}" id="cobertura_2" data-id-validador="cobertura_2_validar"
                onkeyup="veinte(this)" onkeydown="num(this)">
                </td>
              @else
                <td colspan="5"style="text-align:center;color: red;">N O   C U R S A</td>
              @endif
            </tr>
          @endforeach
        @endif
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:click.prevent="AddNotas({{$detalle}})" data-dismiss="modal">Grabar Notas</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark close-btn text-info" wire:click="closeModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
</div>
```

en el boton Grabar Notas llamo a la funcion `AddNotas` y le paso el arreglo `$detalle`, el problema se
presenta en el controlador al hacer un `dd($detalle)` en la funcion `AddNotas` solo muestra el ultimo registro, les escribo para ver si me pueden ayudar, por favor

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que pasaras el ID del elemento que quieres, de tal modo que te quedaria: wire:click.prevent="AddNotas({{$detalle->id}})". Luego ya te encargas de recoger ese ID en tu controlador y utilizarlo para obtener la colección.

Comment: pero necesito la coleccion completa para recorrerla en el controlador e ir guardando las notas en una tabla de la BD

Comment: Cuando pintas AddNotas($detalle), estas usando la variable del foreach, y obviamente es la última iteración, ¿quizás quieres usar $detalle**s** en lugar de $detalle que son todas?

Comment: Buenas, ya intente pero no me retorna el valor de los campos que estan en los inputs, ejemplo ingreso la nota1 para todas las materias del estudiante, pero al hacer un dd($detalles); me muestra $detalles->nota1=""

Comment: Pareces estar usando `livewire`. Puedes editar tu pregunta con el código del componente Livewire?